# How to pass in multidimensional data to xgboost model

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

Essentially this is what I have for xgboost

```
model = XGBClassifier()

model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Where `X_train` and `y_train` are numpy arrays. 
My problem is that `X_train` seems to have to take the format of a numeric matrix where each row is a set of numbers such as:

```
[1, 5, 3, 6]
```

However, the data I have is in the format of a set of vectors. Each vector consists of a number between 1, 3 and a confidence interval that is a between 0, 1. So a row of my `X_train` would look like:

```
[[1, .84], [2, .5], [3, .44], [2, .76]]
```

However I can't figure out how I would pass in data in this format to xgboost.
I'm fairly new to xgboost so I've been reading documentation but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Thanks for any help.

Comment: [[1, .84], [2, .5], [3, .44], [2, .76]] is this a single row or 4 rows with 
 two features ?

Comment: This is a single row. Each feature consists of two parts. So I'm not sure how to input those features into the xgboost model.

Comment: You need to make a single row with 8 features in order to pass to xgboost

Comment: or apply a function to reduce the two parts into a single value. This way you will end up with 4 features. e.g multiply both the part to get [[1*0.84],[2*.5],[3*.44],[2*.76]].

Comment: What would be the best approach so as to not mess up the model? The output is either 1, 2, or 3. Each feature is essentially voting for one of those with some confidence.

Comment: What does the data represent? I mean what does the features in `[[1, .84], [2, .5], [3, .44], [2, .76]]` represent? Is this one sample?

Comment: My program is trying to answer a multiple choice question with the answers being either answer 1, answer 2, or answer 3. I have five different approaches that each pick the answer they think is best with some confidence. Each of these five vectors, consisting of the answer and the confidence, is a feature. The model should then be trained on which feature is most trustworthy at what confidence and should then output the final answer, either 1, 2, or 3.

Comment: You said 5 approaches, but the data shown above has only 4.

Comment: The data above is just an example to show the format that my data is in.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Approach 1**:

I would recommend to make 3 columns for each system, which has the probability of all 3 classes by that system. And then combine these columns for all systems.

Something like this:

```
Index   Sys1_Cls1  Sys1_Cls2  Sys1_Cls3  Sys2_Cls1  Sys2_Cls2  Sys2_Cls3  \
    0   0.310903   0.521839   0.167258   0.034925   0.509087   0.455988   
    1   0.402701   0.315302   0.281997   0.044981   0.137326   0.817693   
    2   0.272443   0.409210   0.318347   0.591514   0.170707   0.237778   
    3   0.272599   0.304014   0.423388   0.175838   0.324275   0.499887   
    4   0.339352   0.341860   0.318788   0.574995   0.169180   0.255824   

       Sys3_Cls1  Sys3_Cls2  Sys3_Cls3  Sys4_Cls1  Sys4_Cls2  Sys4_Cls3  
       0.173293   0.279590   0.547117   0.441913   0.251394   0.306692  
       0.224656   0.425100   0.350244   0.430451   0.382072   0.187476  
       0.198573   0.603826   0.197600   0.412734   0.185472   0.401795  
       0.011399   0.598892   0.389709   0.057813   0.651510   0.290677  
       0.025087   0.478595   0.496317   0.539963   0.288596   0.171440
```

Here `'Sys1_Cls1'` means the probability of System1 for class1 and so on..

This can be your `X`. For `y`, assign the actual class, you have for that sample.

So the shape of your `X` will be `(n_samples, 12)` and `y` will be `(n_samples)`.

If you have more systems, these can be similarly appended as features (Columns).

**Approach 2**:
Other is that you take sum, or average (or weighted average) of all systems for a particular class. In this you will have only 3 columns irrespective of systems.

```
  Index       Cls1      Cls2      Cls3
    0       0.187362  0.151723  0.660914
    1       0.378118  0.293932  0.327950
    2       0.424903  0.278271  0.296825
    3       0.342273  0.274003  0.383723
    4       0.405926  0.104094  0.489981
```

Where the particular values in a column can be:

```
cls1_val = Sys1_Cls1 + Sys2_Cls1 + Sys3_Cls1 + ...

OR

cls1_val = (Sys1_Cls1 + Sys2_Cls1 + Sys3_Cls1 + ...)/number_systems

OR

cls1_val = (weight1 x Sys1_Cls1 + weight2 x Sys2_Cls1 + weight3 x Sys3_Cls1 + ...)/number_systems
```

Here shape of `X`  will be `(n_samples, 3)`

Try with different approaches and keep what works best.

**Note:** By the way, what you are trying to achieve here by combining the probabilities of different systems and then finally predicting a final class is called as Stacking. See these resources for more info:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning#Stacking
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! I was able to input all my data and get reasonable accuracy. Sorry for the late comment.

Comment: @GrantWalton Ok, then please accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to stackoverflow. Thanks for the help